# Python weave blitz DLL error

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to use weave.blitz to speed up some code and I keep getting the following DLL error. If I run a simple code, e.g.

```
from scipy import * # or from NumPy import *
a = ones((512,512),'Float64')
b = ones((512,512),'Float64')

# now average
a[1:-1,1:-1] = (b[1:-1,1:-1] + b[2:,1:-1] + b[:-2,1:-1] \
+ b[1:-1,2:] + b[1:-1,:-2]) / 5.

from scipy import weave
expr = "a[1:-1,1:-1] = (b[1:-1,1:-1] + b[2:,1:-1] + b[:-2,1:-1]" \
    "+ b[1:-1,2:] + b[1:-1,:-2]) / 5."
weave.blitz(expr)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Thijs\wtest.py", line 19, in <module>
    weave.blitz(expr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\blitz_tools.py", line 65, in blitz
    **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\inline_tools.py", line 488, in compile_function
exec 'import ' + module_name
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: Invalid access to memory location.
```

I'm using the latest Pythonxy and I usually write my code in Spyder; not sure if that has anything to do with it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I'm also using python 2.7 64bit/weave.inline under windows 7 and just met the same issue as you described here. I searched the whole internet but this post seems like the only related one and i got no answer.

I traced the weave.inline function and try to load the pyd from compiled binary. Then i found that the loading is successful if i try

`python -c "import sys; sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\\Users\\zliu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\zliu\\python27_compiled'); import sc_d4c0ee9cff8db6a9b5fc8352299944210;"` where the module name being some hash value apparently.

However if I start python interactive then input the exact same statements in the interactive mode, it just shows

> ImportError: DLL load failed: Invalid access to memory location.

So next i tried to compare the output of `python -c -v "..."` and `python -v`, finally i was able to locate the devil different line:

**`import string`**

I have no idea why `python -c` and `python` interactive are different in this or why without this module the import show such an ambiguous message. But putting it at the beginning of the script just works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for posting to such an old thread, and I do not offer an working solution or exaplantion of the problem, it is just a comment. `ImportError: DLL load failed: Invalid access to memory location.` I encountered the same error when trying to make my own extension of Python programmed in C. Platform Windows 32-bit.

It was a real pain because this error appeared randomly in interactive as well as in non-interactive mode in all Python environments (Spyder, Notebook, plain console...). I compiled my code using MinGW and Python's distutils (command `python setup.py install`). The compilation gave no warnings or errors and produced pyd file to the correct directory. But when trying to import this module `import example` pro my Python code it irregularly crashed (usually only one out of five attempts to import the module succeeded).

Strange was that on another computer it worked just fine... Well, I finally found a workaround - I downloaded a newer version of MinGW (before I had used the version that comes packed in Qt SDK distribution) and compiled the module again. Then it worked with no more crashes. However I did not find any systematic solution or explanation. So I might have something to do with the compiler (maybe absence of its DLLs? I do not know exactly) that was used to generate the pyd file.